# How to Print Total number of households based on income brackets. Keeps repeating

Tags: python

This is what I'm getting. The code repeats per how many households sum to each particular bracket:

[image]

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Code:

```
print("Welcome to the San Diego Community Survey")
total_people=[]
total_households=[]
total=[]
count=0
income_total_list = []
new_analysis="yes"
print()
print("Let's get started!")
print()
while new_analysis.lower().strip() =="yes":

    print()
    houses=int(input("How many households would you like to report? "))
    print()
    for i in range(0,houses,1):
        household_n=int(input("How many people in household {}? ".format(i+1)))
        total_households.append(household_n)

        print()
        income_total =0
        for i in range(0,household_n,1):
            x=float(input("What was person {}'s income last year? ".format(i+1)))
            total_people.append(household_n)
            total.append(x)
            income_total = income_total + x
            income_total_list.append(income_total)

        print()
    print()
    print("_________________________________________________________")
    count = len(total_households)
    print("Households analyzed: ", count)
    running_total = 0
    for element in total_households :
        running_total = running_total + element

    print("Number of people in census:", running_total)
    average = sum(total_households) / count
    print("Average people per household:", round(average))
    print()
    print("Average individual income: $",round(sum(total)/len(total),2))

    print("Average household income: $",round(sum(total)/len(total_households),2))
    print()
    print("Income distribution: ")
    for element in income_total_list:

        #print(element)
        if 20000 <= element < 40000:
            print("        At least $20,000 but less than $40,000: household(s)")
        elif 40000 <= element < 60000:
            print("        At least $40,000 but less than $60,000: household(s)")
        elif 60000 <= element <80000:
            print("        At least $60,000 but less than $80,000: household(s)")
        elif 80000 <= element :
            print("        At least $80,000: household(s)")
            print()
    new_analysis= input("Would you like to analyze another area (yes/no): ")
    print()

print("Thanks for participating in our survey!")
```

Comment: the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I would restructure the if statements as follows:

```
  if element>=20000 and element<40000:
        print("        At least $20,000 but less than $40,000: household(s)")
    elif element >=40000 and element<60000:
        print("        At least $40,000 but less than $60,000: household(s)")
.
.
.
and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the code, try putting the print statements outside of the for loop as they only need to occur once. Then inside of the for loop do your calculations on what each loop should produce:

```
small = 0
medium = 0
large = 0
xlarge = 0
for element in income_total_list:

    #print(element)
    if 20000 <= element < 40000:
        small += 1
    elif 40000 <= element < 60000:
        medium += 1
    elif 60000 <= element <80000:
        large += 1
    elif 80000 <= element :
        xlarge += 1

print(f"        At least $20,000 but less than $40,000: {small} household(s)")
print(f"        At least $40,000 but less than $60,000: {medium} household(s)")
print(f"        At least $60,000 but less than $80,000: {large} household(s)")
print(f"        At least $80,000: {xlarge} household(s)")
```